# Lync discards hyperlinks?

Tags: lync

I don't know if it is my Lync configuration or corporate enforced policy but Lync seems to discard hyperlinks. For example if I copy the "formatting help" link on the sidebar here and paste it in a Lync conversation it appears as follows:

```
formatting help » (http://superuser.com/editing-help)
```

The text in parenthesis is *not* clickable for me nor for the person who receives the message.

I don't care much about copy paste, I would be happy to just be able to send clickable links in message. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a Lync server configuration, as described [in this blog](https://blogs.technet.com/b/dodeitte/archive/2009/11/09/options-for-hyperlinks-in-communicator-2007.aspx?Redirected=true):

> Option #2 - Allow instant messages that contain hyperlinks, but
>   convert the links to plain text. Enter the notice that you want to
>   insert at the beginning of each message containing hyperlinks.

Comment: this is a security feature.  By making users cut & paste into a browser.  Hopefully, this will give the user enough time to think whether or not it is a good idea.  I havent seen it recently, but there were viruses that spread through IM clients by infecting a machine and sending out an IM to everyone in the address book with a link to the virus.

Comment: Yes I have seen those too, which I think exploit browser vulnerabilities but in this day and age where everything is clickable it is strange that I can receive links in e-mails, Office documents and PDFs; during work-related chat I have to copy paste to see a JIRA issue. Oh well.